# How can I cat latitude and longitude of Android device?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, android-location, getlocation

So I'm making this app which finds restaurants near you, fetching information from a food-delivery app, using JSoup library.
The only problem with it is that sometimes the latitude and the longitude are getting null value.
Situations in which my application is working:
 -turning on GPS and the waiting at least 1-2 minutes;
 -opening google maps, closing it, and then returning to the application;

So the main problem: I can't fetch the location right after I enable it and hit the 'Find restaurants' button, I need to wait  1-2 minutes after enabling location, then it's working.

```
    private TextView result;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        requestPermission();
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

       getBtn = findViewById(R.id.getRestaurants);
       result = findViewById(R.id.restaurantsList);

       getBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    private void requestPermission(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1 );
    }


public void onClick(View v) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                return;
        }

        client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                result.setText("Getting location...");
                if(location != null){
                double latitude = getLat(location);
                double longitude = getLng(location);

                    result.setText("Finding restaurants near you...");
                getWebsite(latitude, longitude);
                }else{
                    result.setText("Couldn't fetch location!");
                }

            }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way to implement the FusedLocationProvider in Kotlin (you might adapt to Java or use Java and Kotlin side by side) :

```
private fun startLoc() {
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        try {
            fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                    //showDialog(this@MapsActivity, TAG, "last know loc = ${location?.latitude} + ${location?.longitude}")
                    if (location != null){
                        lastKnowLoc = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                        addMarkerToLocation(lastKnowLoc)
                    }
                }
            val locationRequest = LocationRequest()
            locationRequest.interval = 10000
            locationRequest.fastestInterval = 10000
            locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

            locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
                override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
                    locationResult ?: return
                    for (location in locationResult.locations){
                        //showDialog(this@MapsActivity, "locationResult", "location=${location.latitude};${location.longitude}")
                        addMarkerToLocation(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude))
                        val speed = location.speed
                        updateCamera(location.bearing)
                    }
                }
            }

            fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null)

            btnStartLoc.isEnabled = false
            btnStopLoc.isEnabled = true
        }catch (e:SecurityException){}

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you must use `requestLocationUpdates()`
you are using `getLastLocation()` and when  the GPS is off and turned on after the last known location becomes null so you must call `requestLocationUpdates()`
you can find more information in the below link

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates

Comment: Consider posting code as an answer versus a link to a page.