# GOOGLE MAPS API - How to get my position without map.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm confused about how to get my location when clicking a button.

I was trying with my code below:

```java
private void showMyLocation() {
    FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
    Location location = fusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);

    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

and the result is a force close app. I can't read logcat , because logcat is gone when the app crashes.

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: You can find your application logs in the Run tab at the bottom of Android studio even your application is crashed.

Comment: Or you can add try-catch block to catch your exception

Comment: Have you requested the location permission on the device? Little hard to know without seeing the logs. I did make this [location repository](https://github.com/plusmobileapps/location-android) in the past which might help you in the basics of doing location on Android.

Comment: @VishalBari i was do with try catch , and her is catch nothing

Comment: @AndrewSteinmetz yes , i was accepted the request permission

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalRamadhani did you try to open Run tab which is there in the bottom of your screen

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalRamadhani may be this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401709/how-can-i-cat-latitude-and-longitude-of-android-device/59408353#59408353 will help you. thank you

Comment: @VishalBari yes

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create `Location mLocation` as globally then inside onLocationChanged

```java
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;}
```

then

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    // add code 
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                Log.d("MapActivity", "lat of current" + lat);
                lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                Log.d("MapActivity", "lng of current" + lng);

                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }

                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title("You are here!!!")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.a1)));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
            }
        }          
    }
});
```

Comment: implements your class by                                                      implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener                                                                                                                    it will generate override method for you.